# Changing input value with selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, input

I want to change the input value of in the following form:

```
<div class="col-xs-6"><input class="js-order-amount trading-amount trading-price-field textbox pull-left" type="text" maxlength="9" required="required" placeholder="Quantity" value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="How many pieces would you like to buy?"></div>
```

I am using the following code:
`quantity_element= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input[class*="js-order-amount"]')`
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('text',arguments[1])", quantity_element, "6")`

Querying the value with `amount = piece_element.get_attribute("value")` gives me the updated value of "6", but I don't see this value on the userinterface of the website.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 0):

### Selenium Keys:

This can be done simply by using the [Selenium Keys Library](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html). Implement the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

quantity_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "<XPATH_OF_INPUT>")
quantity_element.send_keys("6")
```

Comment: The object maybe obscured. send_keys was the first I was trying, but does not work! Any other hint?

Comment: Try clicking on input element then `send_keys()`  @user19040212